# DB2 batchUpdate with CLOB

Tags: java, batch-file, stored-procedures, db2, clob

I am using DB2 10.5 FP3. I have a stored procedure which insert some data into the database. Part of the data is defined as CLOB. In the JDBC application, I did a batch update. It gives errors:

> [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.19.26] A communication error occurred during
>   operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
>   or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - insufficient
>   data (-1).  Message: Insufficient data. ERRORCODE=-4499,
>   SQLSTATE=08001
>
> [ERROR   ] Problem in executeBatchUpdate. Error for batch element #1:
>   [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.19.26] A communication error occurred during
>   operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
>   or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - insufficient
>   data (-1).  Message: Insufficient data. ERRORCODE=-4499,
>   SQLSTATE=08001
>
> [jcc][10242][10807][4.19.26] Connection is stale. ERRORCODE=-4224,
>   SQLSTATE=null

If I am not using batch, and just use `executeUpdate()` for each records, everything is fine.

Also, I spend some time to debug this. If in the DB side, I changed the parameter of stored procedure from CLOB to VARGRAPHIC, then batch update is fine.

Here is how I prepared the statement:

```
CallableStatement statement;
Clob clob = myConnection.createClob();
clob.setString(1, value);
statement.setClob(paramIndex, clob);
```

Here is how I call the batch:

```
for (int index = 0; index < this.batchSize; index++) {
    setJDBCParametersForBatchEntryAtDB2(statement, index);
    statement.addBatch();// add the statement to the batch
}
statement.executeBatch();// execute the batch commands
```

Any one have suggestions or solutions here?

Comment: Some Code Snippet would be helpfull !!

Comment: I think you need to enable the JDBC trace, [as explained here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvcfgtr.html?lang=en), and collect more diagnostic information.

Comment: Do you turn off autocommit for the batch?

Comment: @mustaccio autocommit is set to TRUE. Will try to enable JDBC trace

Comment: Then set autocommit to FALSE and commit after you execute the entire batch.

Comment: @mustaccio set to FALSE is not an option for my case. For now, i decide to truncate the data to avoid CLOB. I will try to enable JDBC trace later to see if i can figure out something else.

Comment: Why is it not an option? Not even to test if it helps?

Comment: @mustaccio Read some document from [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvbtupd.html) seems like you are right. I have to set the autocommit to false. **If the batched statement is a searched UPDATE, searched DELETE, or MERGE statement, set the autocommit mode for the connection to false**